# NodeJS: cannot grab post request text field

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, formidable

I am new to Node JS, so things are not coming easy to me. The scenario is I have input field which will accept multiple files.

```
<input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple">
```

in my JS script I grab the the change event of this field, and create a post request to my uploader app which is running in different port using `formData` and `ajax` post method

```
$('#upload-input').on('change', function() {
var files = $(this).get(0).files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('directory', "path/to/directory");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://myurl.com:3000/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
});
```

Now the file is sending and in my backend I can upload that using `formidable`, but the problem is I cannot get the `directory` value, Here is my code

```
require('dotenv').load();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var session = require('express-session');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.use('/uploads', express.static(process.env.USER_UPLOADS))
var cors=require('cors');
app.use(cors({origin:true,credentials: true}));
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var user_folder = "path/to/directory/";
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.multiples = true;
    form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, process.env.USER_UPLOADS + user_folder);
    form.on('file', function(field, file) { fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name)); });
    form.on('error', function(err) { console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err); });
    form.on('end', function() { res.end('success'); });
    form.parse(req);
});
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

I tried

```
console.log(req.body)
```

but it returns `undefined`, So how can I get the `directory` value from my backend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You look into something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) NPM package?

Comment: Thanks, it works for me .

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: did you tried using body-parser npm ?

Comment: yeah, and then formidable cannot upload file, returns ` Error: Request aborted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your issue, I made some changes to your main app's server file 
i.e. `server.js/app.js/index.js` anyone that applies to you. See changes below:

```
require('dotenv').load();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var session = require('express-session');
var cors=require('cors');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors({ origin:true, credentials: true }));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(process.env.USER_UPLOADS));


app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var user_folder = "path/to/directory/";
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.multiples = true;
    form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, process.env.USER_UPLOADS + user_folder);
    form.on('file', function(field, file) { fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name)); });
    form.on('error', function(err) { console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err); });
    form.on('end', function() { res.end('success'); });

    // Note the changes here
    form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify({
        fields, // { directory: "path/to/directory" }
        files // contains the uploaded files
    }), null, 2);
  });
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

According to the docs at [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable), `form.parse` can take an optional callback function.

> Parses an incoming node.js request containing form data. If cb is provided, all fields and files are collected and passed to the callback:

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  // ... 
});
```

Comment: Sorry , maybe my question was not clear to you, So let me clarify it again
 
From my js script i am sending the directory address to where the file will save as

    formData.append('directory', "path/to/directory");

and i need that data in my backend, as `var user_folder = "path/to/directory/";`. Another thing i don't know why but `body-parser` and `formidable` not working together. this operation runs almost a  minute and return` Error: Request aborted`

Comment: I even run `console.log(req.body)` and `console.log(form)` but cannot find my directory variable value.

Comment: Yeah, this is what i needed, though finally i couldn't use this.Seems i cannot upload file to a dynamic location which is defined in fields. but now i can access that.